# git stash apply specific index

Tags: git, github

I forked and cloned from upstream https://github.com/F5Networks/k8s-bigip-ctlr, made some local changes in my development branch 'vli-dev', during this process, the upstream made some changes, so I stashed my local changes, rebased my local development branch 'vli-dev' on the upstream master branch, now I want to git stash apply my local changes one by one to the rebased development branch, but following problem occurs:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on vli-dev: 3ef5efd ConfigMap serverssl support with 
f5ServerSslProfileAnnotation
stash@{1}: WIP on vli-dev: 1408dc3 Enable configmap to add custom irule
stash@{2}: WIP on vli-dev: bd6d985 Allow user to attach custom irule to Ingress
stash@{3}: WIP on vli-dev: 2452696 Allow ingress to attach X-Forwarded-For iRule
stash@{4}: WIP on vli-dev: cd01ce5 Route health monitor always default from http monitor regardless what's configured in route health monitor annotation, this patch fix it

$ git stash apply 0
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
pkg/appmanager/resourceConfig.go
schemas/bigip-virtual-server_v0.1.7.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I noticed the local changes are actually the changes stashed in "stash@{1}"

it appears when I git stash apply index 0, the changes in index 1 got applied to the files being changed by index 1, index 0 changes is not applied, how do I resolve this ? my intention is to apply stashed index one by one to resolve any conflicting changes with the upstream, and the create pull request for upstream.

Comment: How did you create all of these stashes?  (As in, what specific commands did you use?)  In the situation you describe, there isn't a reason to have more than one stash (for changes you hadn't yet committed locally), and without understanding what's going on I don't think we can responsibly speculate about how to fix it.

Comment: I originally commited the local changes before rebase my development branch, so I used git reset --soft HEAD^; git stash; to stash these local commits before rebase the development branch

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using stashes to try to do what rebase does, instead of just letting rebase do it.  The only real purpose of stash is to set aside uncommitted changes so they won't be "in the way" of some immediate operation you want to perform.  Once changes are committed, there's no reason to stash them - and in fact, what you're trying to do with stashes is exactly what rebase was designed to do in the first place.

Now I'm assuming you don't currently have any uncommitted changes that you want to preserve.  You can use `git status` to confirm what uncommitted changes, if any, you have.  Once your work tree is clean, I would do this:

(1) Rewind your local branch to its state before you started stashing things.  You can use the reflog for this

```
git reflog vli-dev
```

and this will show you all the commits `vli-dev` has referred to.  Find the last local commit you had made.  It will have a name like `vli-dev@{14}`.  (The number in braces will indicate how many changes ago, so `14` is just an example.)  Then you would

```
git checkout vli-dev
git reset --hard vli-dev@{14}
```

to return your local branch to that state, restoring all the changes you had stashed.  This also undoes the rebase, so next you need to

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This will copy the changes from each of your `vli-dev` commits into a new commit based at the newly-fetched `master` commit.

Now, it would not be unreasonable to be concerned whether the intermediate commits created in this way are actually introducing bugs.  (This is my strongest reservation about many common uses of `rebase`.)  You can certainly check each one out and test it.  If you find an error at some intermediate state, you'll have to decide how much hassle it's worth to fix.  You could, at that point, create a new branch from the broken commit, make the changes so that it passes tests, `git commit --amend`, then rebase the remaining commits onto that newly-amended commit.

The other thing to do is clean up all of those now-unnecessary stashes.  If you had a stash of truly-uncommitted changes, you'll want to apply that on your rebased branch; but the rest can be dropped (`git stash drop`).  Or, if you're absolutely sure that none of the stashes have important data, you could

```
rm .git/refs/stash
rm .git/logs/refs/stash
```

Comment: thanks Mark for the rebase and stash clarification, since these stashes are small changes, I think will manually edit the changes according to the stash and then drop the stash, lesson learned about stash ;)

Answer (score 0):

I want to apply specific stash from the list and for this I used
git stash pop stash@{2}

if you use this command then it will apply that particular stash and remove from stashed list, if you don't want to remove stash then just use
git stash apply stash@{2}

if you want to remove specific stash then use
git stash drop stash@{1}

if you want to clean all stash from list then use
git stash clear

reference : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash